# PHP link not working

Tags: php, ajax, include, require, require-once

I'm trying to `require_once` a file in a document; here's my current syntax:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once("includes/save-email.php");
```

The problem is that, when I reload my page in my browser, every element disappears and I get the following two messages:

```
Warning: require_once(/includes/connect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/3/[my db name]/htdocs/includes/save-email.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/includes/connect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5') in /homepages/3/[my db name]/htdocs/includes/save-email.php on line 2
```

I've tried every variation of the link I can think of, including `../link`, `./link`, `/link`, and `link`.
Strangely enough, when I include an element of the layout using the same overall syntax (replacing `require_once` with `include`), that element loads without any errors, even though it's in the same directory.

I'm not sure that it matters, but my server is run by 1&1.

Comment: My database connection credentials.

Comment: You're talking about save-email.php, but your error references connect.php.  Are you investigating the error in the right place?

Comment: That was an major oversight, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require_once(/includes/connect.php) will look for the file in the root of your server not in the current folder

repalace

```
require_once(/includes/connect.php)
```

by

```
require_once(includes/connect.php)
```

in save-email.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

setting $path won't do anything. you will need to have the includes folder in the same folder as this php document.

Comment: It is in the same folder; this code is an excerpt from my main index.php file, and the /includes folder is in the root, so same level